# Magento 2 - What are the native required attributes to customer and products?

Tags: magento2, customer, products, importexport

When we export the sample of the basic CSV (Customers and Products) at the admin panel on Magento 2 all attributes are exported, whose are the basic attributes to put?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

These are the native attributes requirements.

**Customer basic required attributes:**

- Associate to Website (_website, _store and created_in)
- Group (group_id)
- First Name (firstname)
- Last Name (lastname)
- Email (email)

**Products basic required attributes:**

- Product Name (name)
- Price (price)
- SKU (sku)

On Bundle include these.

- Dynamic SKU (sky_type)
- Dynamic Weight (weight_type)
- Price View (price_view)
- Dynamic Price (price_type)
- Ship Bundle Items (shipment_type)

If you want a complete list you can go on `System > Data Transfer > Import` and select the **Entity Type**, well will show a sample CSV to download.

[image]

Answer (score 3):

As recent as Magento 2.1.8, the default minimum required attributes for importing new products are:

- sku
- attribute_set_code
- product_type
- product_websites
- name
- product_online
- tax_class_name
- price

All of these attributes codes are listed in this tutorial https://www.alexcorradi.org/blog/a-guide-on-how-to-import-export-products-in-magento-2. The tutorial specifies quantity and weight for some reason but they are not actually required.

Additionally, you could always try to manually add a new product in **Product-> Catalog** and click **Add Product**. The required fields will have red asterisks next to them:
[image: Magento 2 required fields to add product]